# Track Changes of an entity / object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I would like to know what the options are to track changes in an entity or object within an MVC application using C# and entity framework?

I have read that a common recommendation is to use property change events to alert when a change happens and then I could potentially do what I need to do on that event.

However I sort of need it to automatically as well newly created items as well, and not just existing properties.

Basically I want an audit trail of what happened and who initiated it to happen.
only track items that are written to the database and basic auditing, like if a company name changed, what was it changed from, what was it changed to, by whom was it changed and when....

what approach is available other than property change, or is there a tool that I can use?

Comment: This is actually a bit tricky, suggest you google, didn't downvote

Comment: Do you want to track http requests? Or you want to track SQL queries to server? Or you want to track changes for any entity, like track each property change? Or you want to track some business actions, like "Complete Order, User Registered, New Product Added" ?

Comment: There are many unclear things here. One example is that you may only want to track **saved** changes, not just _any_ change to a property. E.g. I fetch a user "John Doe", I change the property to "Johnny Doe", then to "Johnny D", and **only then** save the user to the database. Do you want to see the "Johnny Doe" change too, even if that value never reached the database?

Comment: This depends on a lot of factors. What kind of changes are you talking about? To what purpose do you track them and in what detail do you need the information? e.g. you need to know if something was modified (true/false), you need to know which properties were modifed, you need to keep track of changes so you can undo them. Each of those scenarios is different.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments so far, will try to clear it up a bit. 
I am using Entity Frame work (failed to mention that, sorry). I want to implement basic auditing, if company name changed, it changed from what, to what, by whom, when....  and only values being written to the database. 

will something like the ASP.NET Boilerplate Entity History do the trick? it seems to use IEntityHistoryStore

Answer (score 1):

You want an audit trail, so this is something which needs to be done at the database level not at the MVC level.

Every table should have an "updated" column containing the exact UTC date and time of the update, and an "updatedBy" column containing the identity of the user who last updated.

Every time a table changes, you should have a trigger copy the row version to an archive (audit) table. Then you can consult that audit trail at any time to find out who made the most recent change, and also to see any previous version of the row, and even any point-in-time view of the table.

The audit table can (should) be maintained automatically by a trigger.

E.g.:

```
create table Animal (
    id integer primary key,
    name nvarchar(max),
    description nvarchar(max),
    updated datetime,
    updatedBy nvarchar(max)
)

create table AnimalAudit (
    id integer,
    name nvarchar(max),
    description nvarchar(max),
    updated datetime,
    updatedBy nvarchar(max),
    updateAction char(1),
    primary key (id, updated)
)


create trigger TRG_Animal_Audit 
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT AnimalAudit
    select id, name, description, updated, updatedBy, 'C' from INSERTED where not exists (select 1 from DELETED where INSERTED.id = DELETED.id);
    INSERT AnimalAudit
    select id, name, description, updated, updatedBy, 'U' from INSERTED where exists (select 1 from DELETED where INSERTED.id = DELETED.id);
    INSERT AnimalAudit
    select id, name, description, updated, updatedBy, 'D' from DELETED where NOT exists (select 1 from INSERTED where INSERTED.id = DELETED.id);

END
```